# Combining a path in python

Tags: python

In advance, I'm a big noob. I've just started my adventures with python so this question might seem very basic to you. What I'm trying to achieve is creating a simple path by combining a result from cmds.fileDialog2 and a os.path.join.

```
    newDirectory = cmds.fileDialog2(fm = 3, fileFilter = None, ds = 2)
    print newDirectory
```

This gives me the print result.

```
    [u'C:/Users/nyName/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4']
```

i then try to make a combined path that will show a simple image in my UI.

```
    bannerImagePath = os.path.join('newDirectory','/graphic/imageName' + '.jpg')
    print bannerImagePath
```

what I was expecting from this print would be something similar to this due to the path join. C:/Users/nyName/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/graphic/imagename.jpg

but here is what the actual print looks like

```
    /graphic/imageName.jpg
```

TL;DR - Trying to create a combined path by using cmds.fileDialog2 and os.path.join without much luck

Answer (score 4):

The `'newDirectory'` should not be in quotes. It is also a list, so you need to do:

```
bannerImagePath = os.path.join(newDirectory[0],'graphic/imageName.jpg')
```

Note: I have removed the leading slash on the second argument. i.e.

Use:

```
'graphic/imageName.jpg'
```

not:

```
'/graphic/imageName.jpg'
```

**EDIT**

As has been pointed out in the comments, you should normalise the path first before joining:

```
os.path.join(os.path.normpath(newDirectory[0]),'graphic/imageName.jpg')
```

Comment: On Windows, I got this result: `u'C:/Users/nyName/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4\\graphic/imageName.jpg'`

Comment: You should normalize the path with `os.path.normpath(newDirectory[0])`